# I have a refurbished Samsung Galaxy Tab with no Android Market App

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-tab

I bought a refurbished Samsung Galaxy Tab running
Android 2.3.5

1. There is no app for Market on the phone.
2. When I get to market directly, it only shows my Iconia and I've already downloaded things there that I also want on my Galaxy.
3. When I'm told to sign in to google account, it says I can't add that account, it's already there. I'm not trying to add it, I'm trying to sign in through the google system.
4. Skype will not download, either.

Comment: Maybe a factory reset could help too, at least with signing into the google account

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the Market?  I've installed [the 3.4.4 Market from Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/14/download-android-market-3-4-4/) a few times, if you're looking for a safe file.  Just put it on your SD card or internal storage (make sure it has the .apk extension) and install it via a file manager.  `Settings -> Applications -> Unknown sources` needs to be checked for this.